# Using Try & Catch to solve exception

Tags: error-handling, vb.net

I am working on a ADDIN that works on 3D drafting program. This ADDIN has historically grown and now I am doing a big rewrite.

During this rewrite I came across a issue. I have 2 (fairly similar) types of models I am trying to edit using the same code block ADDIN. They both have a property name (inside the 3D drafting progam) that does the same but the property name is different.

This difference is giving me a exception. But I am sure that there is only are two different names.

Is it acceptable to use Try and Catch like this?

```
' Set reference to the user defined property set
Dim oUserProperties As PropertySet =
    ReferencedDocument.PropertySets.Item("Inventor User Defined Properties")

Try
    oUserProperties.Item("Noz_Eccentric").Value = Eccentric
Catch ex As Exception
    oUserProperties.Item("Noz_Radius").Value = Eccentric
End Try
```

OR would it be better to rename the property when the exception is encountered? (sort of a file migration)

```
' Set reference to the user defined property set
Dim oUserProperties As PropertySet =
    ReferencedDocument.PropertySets.Item("Inventor User Defined Properties")

Try
    oUserProperties.Item("Noz_Eccentric").Value = Eccentric
Catch ex As Exception
    oUserProperties.Item("Noz_Radius").Name = "Noz_Eccentric"
    oUserProperties.Item("Noz_Eccentric").Value = Eccentric
End Try
```

Please do not comment on the `o` prefix used. It is common within the 3D drafting program API sample and I kinda inherited this behavior..

Comment: Your question contains **stub code**, there are significant pieces of the core functionality missing, and we need you to fill in the details.  [Excerpts of large projects are fine](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1880/9357), but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is highly specific to the Autodesk Inventor SDK.

While it's not really nice way to check if a property exists, it's documented by Autodesk 
Inventor as the way to do it, since there's not a simple "Check if a property exists" method on the property set (which is very stupid).

The sample in VBA (not VB.Net) that Autodesk Provides [can be found there](http://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-4DAF90F3-EE30-44FE-9AAE-4B04DBD7C582)

The main reason being that catching an Exception can be slower than checking if a method exists.

So in theory if you use this a lot (e.g. 1000 times in a loop), it may be theoreticaly be cleaner/faster/better, to first check which properties are defined, using the method:

```
PropertySet.PropertyInfo()
```

And check if the property exists.

That being said, Inventor may or may not use a COM+ interface which is not too fast.

If performance is not an issue, a practical advice can be to try to set the property and otherwise add it, if it does not exist.

Comment: Is everything between the Try and Catch also slower? Or is it only slower when catching the exception?

Comment: Catching the exception is slower than checking if a variable is set. *IN GENERAL*. For the case of inventor this would really need some benchmarking if this is really the case. This is about miliseconds, and only really an issue if you use a lot of them.